# ASP.NET MVC how to pass parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters

I'd like to have some hidden inputs on View A.aspx and pass the values to Controller. One of the values is a bool, and another one is a char.

How can I get those hidden input values in Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do it simply use Html->Hidden() and then extract the information in controllers parameters like action(char param1, bool param2). if you post true/false then .NET will do the conversion job for you.
Similarly you can append to the query as well.